# Using write.table to create tab separated file with fields which contain commas

Tags: r

I am trying to write a data frame containing installed packages to a tab separated file using write.table:

```
ip <- as.data.frame(installed.packages())
rownames(ip) <- NULL
write.table(ip,file="installed_packages.tsv",quote = F,sep = "\t",row.names = F)
```

Unfortunately this seems to result in a file where commas within a field sometimes result in the creation a new line. However, this is not consistent. Quoting the fields makes no difference. Does anyone have any ideas?
Edit: added an example of the broken output, using quote = T instead:

```
"Package"       "LibPath"       "Version"       "Priority"      "Depends"       "Imports"       "LinkingTo"     "Suggests"      "Enhances"      "License"       "License_is_FOSS"       "License_restricts_use" "OS_type"       "MD5sum"        "NeedsCompilation"      "Built"
"abind" "/home/administrator/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4" "1.4-5" NA      "R (>= 1.5.0)"  "methods, utils"        NA      NA      NA      "LGPL (>= 2)"   NA      NA      NA      NA      "no"    "3.4.4"
"acepack"       "/home/administrator/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4" "1.4.1" NA      NA      NA      NA      "testthat"      NA      "MIT + file LICENSE"    NA      NA      NA      NA      "yes"   "3.4.4"
"addTextLabels" "/home/administrator/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4" "0.0.0.9000"    NA      "R (>= 3.4.4)"  NA      NA      NA      NA      "GPL-3" NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      "3.4.4"
"backports"     "/home/administrator/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4" "1.1.2" NA      "R (>= 3.0.0)"  "utils" NA      NA      NA      "GPL-2" NA      NA      NA      NA      "yes"   "3.4.4"
"ballgownMod"   "/home/administrator/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4" "2.5.3" NA      "R (>= 3.1.1),
methods"        "GenomicRanges (>= 1.17.25),
IRanges (>= 1.99.22),
S4Vectors (>= 0.9.39),
RColorBrewer,
splines,
sva,
limma,
rtracklayer (>= 1.29.25),
Biobase (>= 2.25.0),
GenomeInfoDb"   NA      "testthat,
knitr"  NA      "Artistic-2.0"  NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      "3.4.4"
"base64enc"     "/home/administrator/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4" "0.1-3" NA      "R (>= 2.9.0)"  NA      NA      NA      "png"   "GPL-2 | GPL-3" NA      NA      NA $
"bdsmatrix"     "/home/administrator/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4" "1.3-3" NA      "methods, R (>= 2.0.0)" NA      NA      NA      NA      "LGPL-2"        NA      NA $
"broom" "/home/administrator/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4" "0.5.0" NA      "R (>= 3.1)"    "backports, dplyr, methods, nlme, purrr, reshape2, stringr,
tibble, tidyr"  NA      "AER, akima, AUC, bbmle, betareg, biglm, binGroup, boot, brms,
btergm, car, caret, coda, covr, e1071, emmeans, ergm, gam (>=
1.15), gamlss, gamlss.data, gamlss.dist, geepack, ggplot2,
glmnet, gmm, Hmisc, irlba, joineRML, Kendall, knitr, ks,
Lahman, lavaan, lfe, lme4, lmodel2, lmtest, lsmeans, maps,
maptools, MASS, Matrix, mclust, mgcv, muhaz, multcomp, network,
nnet, orcutt (>= 2.2), ordinal, plm, plyr, poLCA, psych,
quantreg, rgeos, rmarkdown, robust, rsample, rstan, rstanarm,
sp, speedglm, statnet.common, survey, survival, testthat,
tseries, xergm, zoo"    NA      "MIT + file LICENSE"    NA      NA      NA      NA      "no"    "3.4.4"
```

I note that a new line is also created for the line ending 'gam (>='. I also observe that the file opens ok in libre-office calc with the fields delimited correctly (but only when using the quote = T option) but not using nano, vi, or the default ubuntu text editor (with either quote = T or quote = F). So this has something to do with the text editor....

Comment: Can not reproduce your problem `quote = TRUE` seems to fix anything. Can you add the broken output example?

Comment: Added broken output as displayed in nano. You are right that quote = TRUE fixes the problem, at least when opening the tsv in libre-office calc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should do the trick:

```
a <- installed.packages()
a <- a[, 1]
names(a) <- c() # optional line
write.table(a, "installed.tsv", quote = F, sep = "\t", row.names = F)
```

The result of installed.packages() is a messy matrix, so you need to subset it correctly to get just the vector of all packages.

Result in R:

```
[1] "abind"               "Amelia"              "ape"              "assertthat"         
[5] "backports"           "base"                "base64enc"        "BBmisc"             
[9] "BelgiumMaps.StatBel" "BH"                  "bindr"            "bindrcpp"
```

Result in TextEdit (Mac):

```
abind
Amelia
ape
assertthat
backports
base
base64enc
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Worked but I also needed to add col.names = F

Answer (score 0):

You can directly write the data frame using :

```
 write.csv(ip,"installed_packages.csv")
```

Here, commas within a field won't result in the creation of a new line.

Comment: This gives the exact same behaviour as my code above.